# Is there a 'writeable' test for a net.socket connection in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets

Is there a 'writeable' or connected test for a net.socket connection in node.js? Or do I have to do something like this:

```
var client = new net.Socket();
var isConnected = false;
client.connect(5555, 192.168.0.150, function() { isConnected = true; });
client.on('close', function() { isConnected = false; });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to check `client.writable`.

Comment: Where is this documented? (I am sure I could learn more than just the answer to my question.)

Comment: It was documented before streams2 landed in v0.9.4. I don't know why it or the readable property are longer in the streams docs. Both readable/writable properties are even still used in node core.